# Why am I getting a Syntax error when using "class" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I am making a game in javascript, and I'm using making a class to hold all the sprites. However when I try to run it, safari gives me "SyntaxError: Unexpected use of reserved word 'class'". I can't find a reason it should be doing this. Below is my code:

```
var spritesContext;

//Sprite class
class sprite{
    constructor(imageName, imageX, imageY, imageHeight, imageWidth, context, canvas){
        this.imageName = imageName;
        this.imageX = imageX;
        this.imageY = imageY;
        this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
        this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.context = context;
        spritesContext = context;
        console.log("Sprite constructed");
    }

    draw(){
        var character = new Image();
        character.src = "../Images/" + this.imageName + ".png";
        character.onload = function(){
            spritesContext.drawImage(character, this.imageX, this.imageY, this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
            console.log("Inner Draw is working.");
        }
        console.log("Draw is working.");
    }

    function getHeight(){
        return this.imageHeight;
    }

    function getWidth(){
         return this.imageWidth;
    }

    function getX(){
        return this.imageX;
    }

    function getY(){
       return this.imageY;
    }

    function moveUpX(e){
        this.imageX = (this.imageX + e);
    }

    function moveUpY(e){
        this.imageY = (this.imageY + e);
    }

    function moveBackX(e){
        this.imageX = (this.imageX - e);
    }

    function moveBackY(e){
       this.imageY = (this.imageY - e);
    }

    function changeImage(e){
        this.imageName = e;
    }

    function getImage(){
       return this.imageName;
    }

    function changeX(e){
         this.imageX = e;
    }

    function changeY(e){
        this.imageY = e;
    }

}
```

Comment: "class" is a new thing -- what version of javascript engine are you using?

Comment: It's a keyword in ES6.  What browser/environment are you using this in?

Comment: You can't declare functions inside a class like that, that's an error

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work, and more specifically the keyword *class*, you need to be in strict mode to enable certain browsers to interpret it.

To be in strict mode, add the following to the top of your file:

```
'use strict';
```

Comment: To clarify a little: the language itself does not require `strict mode` to use these features, but the browsers that are rolling them out have enabled some in strict mode before standard mode.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment. Thanks.

Comment: And, at least Chrome is sensible enough to throw errors like `..class not yet supported outside strict mode`, not `Unexpected use...`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Safari did not support "class" when the question was asked.